# Regex only matches last occurrence reading left to right

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have this string.

`Votre vol :  Casablanca  -  Paris  Mercredi 31 août 2016  AF1197  -  Ecoi 7 septembre 2016  AF1196  -  Economy  15:20  Paris  ,  Charles de Gaulle (CDG)  ,  FRANCE  -  Terminal  2E  Heure Limite d'Enregister un supplément.`

With the following regex

`(?:Votre vol|Your flight)(.*?([0-9]{1,2}\s[^\s]+?\s[0-9]{4}))+`

I want to capture `31 août 2016` and `7 septembre 2016` in different groups.

If I remove the last date the first date is captured.

(Python Flavor)

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/hyCZab/3)

Comment: You need to use 2 groups then - [`Votre vol\s*:.*?([0-9]{1,2}\s+\S+\s+[0-9]{4}).*?([0-9]{1,2}\s+\S+\s+[0-9]{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/2ec9cG/1). You only get as many groups as you define in the regex pattern.

Comment: BTW, why not use `re.findall(r'\b[0-9]{1,2}\s+\S+\s+[0-9]{4}\b', s)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I do not use 2 groups because it can be 3 4 or 5 and I need `Votre vol` in the regex or else it will match another string in a for loop, explaining why I don't do findall

Comment: Then do it in two steps: 1) Use your regex and then 2) apply `re.findall` as in my above comment on the extracted string. Or you need to use PyPi regex library that stores each capture per group.

Comment: I was afraid that that would be the best option. If there's no best way I'm sticking to that. Make it an answer having in mind our comments

Comment: There's only one pattern on your string, the flight number, 2 letters + x digits, work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no way to keep all the captured substrings within a group using `re`, you can't but follow the following 2-step process:

- Extract the substring(s) with your current regex
- Then, extract the dates using a subpattern like `re.findall(r'\b[0-9]{1,2}\s+\S+\s+[0-9]{4}\b', s)` (see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kbkvtT/2)).

With a PyPi `regex` module, you could get all the necessary results using 1-pass approach since that library stores all captures per group.

A small note on your regex: `[^\s]+?\s` can be written as `\S+\s` since `[^\s]` matches any char other than whitespace, and `+?` lazy quantifier will make matching a bit slower than it could be with a greedy `+` (`\s` is the opposite shorthand character class, so `\S+\s` is optimal here).